# Error when trying to install gem websocket-driver-0.7.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

When I try to install the websocket-driver-0.7.3 gem, I get this message on CMD:

```
Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.3
Installing websocket-driver 0.7.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.3/ext/websocket-driver
C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r
./siteconf20201109-15264-1prb1qx.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.3/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory:
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.3/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR="
make failedNo such file or directory - make "DESTDIR="

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.3 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.7.0/websocket-driver-0.7.3/gem_make.out
```

I'm using ruby 2.7.0. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to similar issue on github repo, you should do the following:

- install MSYS2 DevKit
- run `ridk install`

for further information refer to [the issue](https://github.com/faye/websocket-driver-ruby/issues/54#issuecomment-327102938) on github.

and ruby [installer](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2#using-the-installer-on-a-target-system) for windows.

Answer (score 0):

rvm install ruby-3.0.1 --with-gcc